# Redirect page if redux dispatch is success

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, history

I only want to redirect if the post request is success on submit/onKeyDown using history.push(). The trouble is the function for my post request is in Redux Thunk.
While there is a way to create custom history and import history in redux and use history.push() in action/thunk I don't want to do that. I would like to keep history.push() in my React component. How can I do this?

My post function in my react component

```
const [patientName, setPatientName] = useState('');

const handlePatientNameChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setPatientName({ [name]: value });
};

const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(postRoomPatient(patientName, roomId));
        // if dispatch is success history.push('/home')
    }
};

// if error true - post is fail otherwise success.
 const roomPatientError = useSelector((state) => state.roomPatients[roomId] && state.roomPatients[roomId].error);
```

my redux reducer/action

```
const roomPatientsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'roomPatients',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
   
      setPatientSuccess: (state, action) => {
        const { patientName, roomId } = action.payload;
        const prevState = state[roomId];
        state[roomId] = {
          ...prevState,
          patientName: patientName,
          error: false,
       };
     },
   }
});


export const postRoomPatient = (patientName, roomId) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('/patient/add', patientName, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
        });

        const patientName = await response.data;
        dispatch(setPatientSuccess({ patientName, roomId }));
        // if success I want to history.push (`/home`) but do it in my React component 
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

Comment: In your component, you could subscribe to redux store and check if `patientName` is set or not. If it is , render a `Redirect` component that redirects to `/home`

Comment: you can declare a `success` variable in `setPatientSuccess:` in reducer, and then by getting this `success` variable from state in react component you can use history there. like `if(useSelector(state=> state.reducer.sucess)) then history.push('/');`

Comment: Return a promise from your action and redirect the page within ```.then```

Comment: @bakar_dev thank you for your comments. I have edited my post with a useSelector and it listens to if setPatientSuccess action is success however trouble is the initial state of the error value is false. therefore is will always redirect

Comment: @Jereme so dont check for `error` in this case, only use that variable that is changing only on `success` action.

Comment: @bakar_dev even if I check success: true. the next time I go in the form it'll redirect me immediately bc at that point success will still be true

Comment: @Jereme yeah i know :) for this you need to add an another `function` , i.e `setPatientLoading` in reducer and set `success` to `false` in this, and call this function every time before requesting API, in the `postRoomPatient` function right after the try statement dispatch it, actually this is used for loading purpose. (i.e. waiting for api to return data)